# Powershell Import-CSV with Custom Function Parameter Binding

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell and I am trying to understand how to pass items through the pipeline to a custom function.  For example, I have a CSV file that looks something like this:

```
Url,Email
"http://www.google.com","myemail@gmail.com"
"http://www.yahoo.com", "myemail@yahoo.com"
```

and a function that looks somewhat like this:

```
Function HelloWorld() {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        Param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
            [string]$Url,

            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
            [string]$Email)
    Proces {
        Write-Host $Url $Email
    }
}
```

I would like the command to work something like this:

> Import-CSV C:\temp\myfile.csv | HelloWorld -Url {$*.Url} -Email
>   {$*.Email}

However I am getting the following error:

> HelloWorld : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for
>   the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or
>   the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that
>   take pipeline input.

Understanding that I am new to PowerShell how would I get this simple example working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you decorate each parameter with the `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` attribute you'll be you'll be able to bind the values via the pipeline and call the function like so:

```
Function HelloWorld() {

        [CmdletBinding()]

        Param(
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
            [string]$Url,

            [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
            [string]$Email
       )

    Process {
        Write-Host $Url $Email
    }
}

Import-CSV C:\temp\myfile.csv | HelloWorld
```

Notice that for this to work, parameter names must be named the same as the incoming object properties (otherwise you need to use an alias).

Without the above you could call the function using the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet:

```
Import-CSV C:\temp\myfile.csv | Foreach-Object { HelloWorld -Url $_.Url -Email $_.Email }
```